# xaml image from URL not loading

Tags: android, image, xaml, xamarin

I'm Quite new to both c# and xaml, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I'm trying to dynamically add images to a grid (like this), however the image(s) never appear, i just have a red box appear (the background).

```
Image img = new Image { 
    BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
    HeightRequest = 150,
    WidthRequest = 150,
    Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://i.imgur.com/qcm7iUe.png")),
}
GridItems.Children.Add(img);
```

p.s. ive tried several links none of which work, but local images "c:/image.png" seem to work fine.

[edit]

1) This appears to work fiine in vs2017, but does not work in vs2019.

2) I read that this could be an issue because of the "http**s**" however my project already has TLS2.1+ set.

Comment: have you tried loading the url from the device (or emulators) browser?  Does your app have the necessary permissions to use the internet?

Comment: the app loads and runs off of my phone when I build/Run. how do I check/set permissions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/android-internet

Comment: well, i added the permissions (thanks) but still no images appearing.

Comment: did you try my other suggestion - loading in the device browser?  Did you check the app output log for any messages related to those urls?

Comment: yes, the image shows up fine in Chrome (on the phone). not sure where the app output log is yet, im looking for it :o

Comment: I ran the project from vs2017 (on my tablet) and it worked fine, but when I run it from vs2019 the images don't show. cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue was related to outdated nuGet packages? after installing updates images are now appearing.